# What is Krumo, and why should I care?

Tags: debugging

What is Krumo, and when enabled, what does it do for a CiviCRM site?

Comment: Since Krumo has nothing to do with CiviCRM, it would help if you provided some more explanation about how you came across it and why it seemed to be related.

Comment: Coleman, yes absolutely. We upgraded to CiviCRM 4.6 recently. We apparently have Krumo on our Debian server, which is running Drupal and CiviCRM, for debugging. Trying to figure out a few issues with the 4.6 install. Nothing wrong with Krumo, it's doing what is supposed to do. I did find more info about Krumo at krumo.sourceforge.net .

Answer (score 5):

Krumo is part of the Drupal Devel module.  If you want to print out debugging statements in Drupal, you can put this line in your code:

```
dsm($myvariable);
```

It will print out the variable info with much more nicely-formatted HTML than just print_r() or similar.

In CiviCRM, I don't use this - I prefer

require_once 'CRM/Core/Error.php';

CRM_Core_Error::debug('variablename', $variablename).

There are variations on that available here: http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=33129619

Though [this page](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/pages/editpage.action?pageId=88932428) seems to suggest that maybe the variations are deprecated.

Comment: Jon, thanks so much, checking out those other debugging options.